# I don't understand why and how i can fix soft keyboard open and close automatically in Fragment Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I have added an AutoCompleteTextView to my android project but when I click on the AutoCompleteTextView, the keyboard appears and disappears in a second.

But if I click the AutoCompleteTextView and quickly click on some characters, the keyboard doesn't disappear.

I do not understand why. How can I fix it?

if you need another piece of code ask me.

**This is the Fragment.java**

```
package com.example.trasporti;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.trasporti.adapter.PlaceAutoSuggestAdapter;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place;
import com.here.sdk.core.errors.InstantiationErrorException;
import com.here.sdk.search.SearchEngine;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link LocationFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class LocationFragment extends Fragment {

View layoutView;


TextView text1,text2,text3;



public LocationFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static LocationFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    LocationFragment fragment = new LocationFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {

    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location,container,false);

    MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    Context context = mainActivity.getContextF();
    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(new PlaceAutoSuggestAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1));


   // text1 = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
    //text2 = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.TextView2);
    //text3 = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.TextView3);




    return layoutView;
}


}
```

**This is Fragment layout**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="#0F1D49"
tools:context=".LocationFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->



<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:shadowColor="@color/white"
    android:textColorHint="@color/grey"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:hint="Cerca la destinazione"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
    />

<!---<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/TextView1"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/TextView2"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/TextView3"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    />-->
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have followed up your code and make it a demo but nothing happens just like you mentioned. If your view is static, then moving any code to the onActivityCreated method is not necessary. But when you - for instance, fill some lists from the adapter, then you should do it in the onActivityCreated method. Please check it out below:

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        AutoCompleteTextView editText = findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.custom_list_item, R.id.text_view_list_item, countriesList);
        editText.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    }
```

Your Fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#0F1D49"
    >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:shadowColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/teal_200"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:hint="Cerca la destinazione"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

text_view_list_item

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_list_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/teal_200"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/teal_700" />
    </LinearLayout>
```